# Xamarin throws a type or namespace error when attempting to create a table in a SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to create a table into a SQLite database. When I go to debug, I get a 'type or namespace error' for the table name.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "fcdb.sqlite");
                using (var connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath))
                {
                    connection.CreateTable<CounselingEmotionalSupport> (0);
                };
```

The error is thrown at the CounselingEmotionalSupport line. I can't seem to resolve this, even though I have tried naming the string initially and there is no refactor or resolve solution.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake #102012 - the class name was Counseling not CounselingEmotionalSupport.